# how can i add more ids on php code on woocommerce for custom content for products?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to the PHP world, I wanted to ask, how can I add more product ids to this code?

Unfortunately I don't know how to separate multiple IDs.

I would like to enter multiple ids so that specific content is only displayed for certain products.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_custom_content_for_specific_product', 15 );
function add_custom_content_for_specific_product() {
    global $product;

    // Limit to a specific product ID only (Set your product ID below )
    if( $product->get_id() != 37 ) return;

    // The content start below (with translatables texts)
    ?>
        <div class="custom-content product-id-<?php echo $product->get_id(); ?>">
            <h3><?php _e("My custom content title", "woocommerce"); ?></h3>
            <p><?php _e("This is my custom content text, this is my custom content text, this is my custom content text…", "woocommerce"); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php
    // End of content
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you adding the `ID`s manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to the content to show on specific products, you can use [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_custom_content_for_specific_product', 15 );
function add_custom_content_for_specific_product() {
    global $product;

    /* Add the product ids to the array separated by commas that you want the content below to display on
     * in_array() arguments:
     * $product->get_id() is the needle - what you're looking for in the array
     * [1,2,3,4,5] are the product ids you want to show the content on. Replace those with your actual ids
     * TRUE just makes sure it's the same type of data. In this case we set it to TRUE, since $product->get_id() is an integer and so is the data in the array.
    */ 
    if( in_array( $product->get_id(), [37,1,2,3,6,7], TRUE ) ) :

    // The content start below (with translatables texts)
    ?>
        <div class="custom-content product-id-<?php echo $product->get_id(); ?>">
            <h3><?php _e("My custom content title", "woocommerce"); ?></h3>
            <p><?php _e("This is my custom content text, this is my custom content text, this is my custom content text…", "woocommerce"); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php
    /* If the ids are not in the array above, return the function without output. */
    else :
        return;
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help wordpress shows me a syntax error here that I can't find, do you see it?

`if( in_array( $product->get_id(), [37,1,2,3,6,7], TRUE ) :`

Comment: Yep! I forgot a closing parenthesis on the `if` statement. I fixed it in the code above.